# How do I get the user's email after signing up with Django All Auth?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have a django project that uses django all auth for signing up users.

After the user enters username, email and password in the signup form:

- a confirmation emal is sent to their inbox to click and confirm the registration
- they get redirected to a page displaying that they should check their inbox for the confirmation link

I want in that page, before clicking the link, to display the email that the user has used to sign up.

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I want to get the email address the user used to signup before clicking the link in the email sent to confirm the registration.